# Kohana DB last insert id before insert

Tags: mysql, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I have a table with **autoincrement ID**.

I have to generate serials based on its `id prior the insert` I could find the highest ID value, but what if there is was delete before, and the AUTO INCREMENT of the

`table != max(id)+1`

Answer (score 0):

Break this up into two queries.

1. Run an insert query to retrieve the id.
2. Create the serial from the retrieved id.
3. Use an update query to add the serial value to the record.

Example code using the ORM Module

```
$my_table = ORM::factory('Mytable');

$my_table->field1 = 'Value1';
$my_table->field2 = 'Value2';

$my_table->save(); // inserts record

// Create serials (will obviously be more complex than this)  
$my_table->serial = $my_table->id;

$my_table->save(); // updates record
```

Example code using the Database Module

```
list($id) = DB::insert('my_table', array('field1','field2'))  
->values(array('value1','value2')  
->execute();

// Create serials (will obviously be more complex than this)  
$serial = $id;

DB::update('my_table')  
->set(array('serial' => $serial))  
->where('id', '=', $id);
```